# Eliminating CSS selectors when parsing with Nokogiri?

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I am retrieving the latest news articles from cnn.com website, and wrote a simple Nokogiri script to do this:

```
url = "http://edition.cnn.com/?refresh=1"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("title").text
  doc.css("#cnn_maintt2bul div+ div a").each do |headline|
  article = headline.text
  puts "#{article}"
end
```

The problem is, CNN posts a mixture of articles and links to videos. Now I am only interested in articles not videos. When I run this script it retrieves all articles but leaves a space when an article links to a video, for example.

```
Pakistan airstrikes kill dozens
Could U.S. leave Afghanistan?
Editor's stabbing draws outrage
Ukrainian city fears uprising

U.S. hate groups in decline
```

This would mean that `Ukrainian city fears uprising` would actually link to a video. It would do this until it retrieves the last article.

I discovered that the articles have a selector called `.cnnVideoIcon`. Any ideas about how I could eliminate this such that articles linking to videos are removed from my results?

How would I eliminate such links when am parsing? They could appear anywhere.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site you are scraping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the HTML source code of the CNN site and found that the "li" tag of a video headline has four child elements, and only three child elements with text headlines.

```
<li class="c_hpbullet3" data-vr-contentbox=""> 
   <span class="cnnPreWOOL"></span> 
   <a href="/video/data/2.0/video/world/2014/02/25/ctw-ukraine-political-aftermath-ian-bremmer-intv.cnn.html?hpt=hp_t5">Ukrainian politics remain in flux</a> 
   <span class="cnnPostWOOL"></span> &nbsp;
   <a href="/video/data/2.0/video/world/2014/02/25/ctw-ukraine-political-aftermath-ian-bremmer-intv.cnn.html?hpt=hp_t5" target=""><img class="cnnVideoIcon" width="16" height="10" border="0" alt="Ukrainian politics remain in flux" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/icons/video_icon.gif"></a> 
</li>
```

So, we can use the XPath syntax below:

```
doc.xpath("//div[@id='cnn_maintt2bul']/div/div/ul/li[count(*)=3]/a").each do |headline|
  article = headline.text
  puts "#{article}"
end
```

Comment: How would I get the links to each article such they are clickable and also retrieve the first paragraph of each article.

Comment: Could you help me out with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055544/getting-visiting-and-limiting-the-number-of-links-using-nokogiri-and-mechanize

Answer (score 0):

You should use something else than the CSS attributes to find the desired tags. Use `search` instead of `css` and give it an XPath that only selects the elements that don't have the link to a video as child.

I will update the answer with a designated XPath when you provide a real URL to the site you want to fetch information from.

Comment: The url is the exact url in the script a shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of the blocks you're scraping from http://edition.cnn.com/?refresh=1, you will notice that videos are a link with a video icon (and no text), like so:

```
<a href="/video/data/...">
   <img class="cnnVideoIcon" alt="Ukrainian city fears uprising" ... 
        height="10" width="16">
</a>
```

This explains why you get some empty lines.

You could skip those links using a more refined selector like:

```
#cnn_maintt2bul div + div a:empty
```

Using `a:empty`, you will only retrieve links without images or other elements inside, or, in other words, all links with a description text only.

---

Another (less optimized) approach is to simply skip the empty lines with an `if` statement:

```
doc.css("#cnn_maintt2bul div + div a").each do |headline|
article = headline.text
if (article != "")
    puts "#{article}"
...
```